# how to initialize masonry on ajax call

Tags: ajax, facebook, jquery-masonry

I am showing facebook posts via facebook graph and using masonry.
Default masonry initialization:

```
$('#facebook-feed').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true
});
```

Default facebook posts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var accessToken ='xxx';

        //$("#mainContainer").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/abc/posts?fields=full_picture,id,is_published,link,story,message,name,updated_time,description,from,source,caption,created_time,permalink_url,type,target&access_token=' + accessToken + '&limit=5',
            type: 'GET',

            success:function(result){
                $.each( result.data, function( index, value ) {
                    var link;
                    var imgSrc = '';
                    var name = '';
                    var message = '';
                    if(typeof(value.link) != "undefined" && value.link !== null) {
                            link = value.link;
                        } else {
                            link = value.permalink_url;
                        }
                        if(typeof(value.full_picture) != "undefined" && value.full_picture !== null) {
                            imgSrc = value.full_picture;
                        }
                        if(typeof(value.name) != "undefined" && value.name !== null) {
                            name = value.name;
                        }
                        if(typeof(value.message) != "undefined" && value.message !== null) {
                            message = value.message;
                        }
                    $("#facebook-feed").append(
                        '<div class="grid-item"><a href="'+value.permalink_url+'" target="_blank">'+
                            '<div class="thumbnail">'+
                            '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" alt="'+name+'" >'+
                            '<div class="caption">'+
                            '<h3>'+name+'</h3>'+
                            '<p>'+message+'</p>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</a></div>'
                    );
                });
            },
            error:function() {
                $("#facebook-feed").html('Failed To Load Resource');
            }
        });
    });
```

Now I have load more feed button which is used to load more feeds based on limit.

```
$(document).on("click", "#load-more-feeds", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#hidden-next-feed").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                $("#hidden-next-feed").val(result.paging.next);
                $.each( result.data, function( index, value ) {
                    var link;
                    var imgSrc = '';
                    var name = '';
                    var message = '';
                    if(typeof(value.link) != "undefined" && value.link !== null) {
                        link = value.link;
                    } else {
                        link = value.permalink_url;
                    }
                    if(typeof(value.full_picture) != "undefined" && value.full_picture !== null) {
                        imgSrc = value.full_picture;
                    }
                    if(typeof(value.name) != "undefined" && value.name !== null) {
                        name = value.name;
                    }
                    if(typeof(value.message) != "undefined" && value.message !== null) {
                        message = value.message;
                    }
                    var moreFeeds = '<div class="grid-item"><a href="'+value.permalink_url+'" target="_blank">'+
                        '<div class="thumbnail">'+
                        '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" alt="'+name+'" >'+
                        '<div class="caption">'+
                        '<h3>'+name+'</h3>'+
                        '<p>'+message+'</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</a></div>';
                    var $moreFeeds = $( moreFeeds );
                    // Append new blocks
                    $("#facebook-feed").find("div.grid-item:last").after( $moreFeeds );
                    // Have Masonry position new blocks
                    $("#facebook-feed").find("div.grid-item:last").masonry( 'appended', $moreFeeds );
                    /*$("#facebook-feed").find("div.grid-item:last").after(
                        '<div class="grid-item"><a href="'+value.permalink_url+'" target="_blank">'+
                        '<div class="thumbnail">'+
                        '<img src="'+imgSrc+'" alt="'+name+'" >'+
                        '<div class="caption">'+
                        '<h3>'+name+'</h3>'+
                        '<p>'+message+'</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</a></div>'
                    );*/
                })
            },
            error:function() {
                $("#facebook-feed").html('Failed To Load Resource');
            },
        })
    })
```

The facebook posts is coming fine but the masonry isn't working. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: small side comment: you are doing a lot of things with jquery that are really not neccessary. for example: $("#hidden-next-feed").val() - this would be a lot faster and exactly as easy with vanilla js: document.getElementById('hidden-next.feed').value - learn vanilla js first, and then use jquery only when you REALLY need it. for jquery based plugins, for example. for ajax, there is the fetch api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('#facebook-feed').masonry('reloadItems');` to reload items but if it doesn't work you can destroy  the masonry instance with `$('#facebook-feed').masonry('destroy');` and re-initialize it again.

You can check all the available methods [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html).

Comment: No it's nt working. When used it shows only one feed. Think its overlapped.

Comment: Ok did you tried `destroy` and then re-initializate it again?

Comment: Ok I'm editing the answer. Please approve it if it's fine